How does the word "it" function in: "What is it that makes us uneasy ... ?"

What is it that makes us uneasy about accepting credit for something wonderful we have done?

In this sentence, how does the word "it" function?
Is it a pronoun or a dummy subject?
Or is it part of a cleft sentence "It be ... that"?

"It" refers to the quality of human beings that makes us behave like that.

Yes, a personal pronoun functioning as dummy subject. "What" is a fronted predicative complement accompanied by obligatory subject-auxiliary inversion.

It could be rephrased as "What makes us uneasy about accepting credit for something wonderful we have done?"

This is essentially the same: "What is it about us..." This clarifies that Kate above is right: "it" is "that thing about us that makes us behave like that."

It is the subject and it’s a dummy subject. What is it that makes us...? It is human nature that makes us.... Human nature makes us....

Other than emphasis, does anyone see a difference between 'What is it that makes us...' and the more simple 'What makes us…'?



What is it that makes us uneasy about accepting credit for something wonderful we have done?


The original Poster asks three questions about their example:

What's the function of the word it?
Is it a pronoun or dummy subject?
Is it part of a cleft sentence "It be ... that ..."

So here goes:
The word it is a meaningless non-referential pronoun  functioning as the dummy Subject of the verb BE.
The example is the interrogative version of the following sentence where 'X' represents the noun phrase represented by the word what:


It is 'X' [that makes us uneasy about accepting credit for something wonderful we have done].


In the sentence above the word it functions as the Subject. The noun phrase X (the word what in the interrogative sentence in example (1)) is the Predicative Complement of that verb. The sentence is a cleft sentence and the relative clause in brackets is the backgrounded part of the cleft, which functions as a second Complement of the verb is.
In the Original Poster's interrogative version of the sentence, the interrogative word What has been fronted and verb is has been moved to the position in front of the Subject, the word it. This is  what we normally see in open-interrogative main clauses.

Consider this reformulation of the question: 'Something makes us uneasy about accepting credit for something wonderful we have done. What is it?' In this reformulation it clearly does have a definite referent: the 'something' referred to in the first sentence. Can we be confident that the way it functions in the original formulation is completely different from the way it functions in this reformulation?

@jsw29 I disagree that it is clearly referential there. Clear way to illustrate the problem "Someone stole the diamond. Who is it?" <--That it is not referential. It's a shortened it-cleft. We don't use it to refer to people. In contrast "Someone stole the diamond. Who are they" <-- There they clearly are referential. Would you claim that in "It's Mary who stole the diamond", the word it  refers to Mary? It doesn't seem likely, does it? What do you think?

@jsw2 Er Should have written "Clearly, they is referential*"

When the question was first posted, I started answering it along the lines of my first comment. The arguments on the other side, similar to those in your response, then occurred to me, and I had to acknowledge their force, but they did not entirely remove the intuitive pull of the other ones. I thus found it difficult to be confident about the matter either way, and gave up the attempt to answer the question. Hence the cautious formulation in my comment ('can we be confident').

If ‘it’ here were replaced by ‘the thing’, as I think it can legitimately be, would it still be a dummy?

@AntonSherwood Hmm "It is water that boils at one hundred degrees" does not seem to mean the same as "The thing is water which boils at one hundred degrees". The answer to the specific question, though, is "no". Grammarians would usually say that a fully fledged NP with a determiner and common noun head can't be a dummy.

True enough, but I am not convinced that it is parallel enough.  And with that I plead nolo contendere.

Is there zero semantic difference in What makes people so gullible? and What is it that makes people so gullible?

@TimR Has anyone said there's no difference?

@Araucaria-Him Has anyone said there is some difference?

@TimR If you're asking if there's a difference in meaning between the two constructions, there is, but it's easier to see with a different example. See my answer here and the discussion below it.


What

-> complement of "is"

is

Copula

it

Subject = that thing

that makes us uneasy

relative clause modifying "it"

about (=in the matter of) accepting credit for something wonderful we have done?

prepositional phrase (adverbial) modifying "uneasy".

But "it" does not mean "that thing" here. Consider: "Who was it who stole the diamond?" Or "It was Jill who stole the diamond". Do you think the word "it" refers to Jill there? Wouldn't you expect "she" instead? The word "it" doesn't refer to anything in an it-cleft construction. It's just a dummy placeholder.

Also, the relative clause is not "that makes us uneasy". It's "that makes us uneasy about accepting credit ... done" the adjective phrase "easy ... done" is a single constituent!

@Araucaria-Him Well, they are possible opinions, I suppose. However, "Who was it who stole the diamond?" -> "Who was the person/thief who stole the diamond?" A sentence with a dummy it can be rearranged to avoid the "it" - It won't do any good to hide from me. -> To hide from me won't do any good .
